# Displaying the value of a textbox in other parts of a report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

In a report table there is this formula to calculate a subtotal for an invoice. This is the formula:

```
=Sum(Fields!LineTotal.Value)
```

The textbox is called TextBoxSubTotal. I would like to display this in another part of the report such as in the header area where I display that subtotal, tax, shipping charge and also a total due.

Can you tell me how to display this value in TextBoxSubTotal in other parts of the report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried creating a report variable? Create a new variable and put the invoice calculation into the expression for the new variable. Then reference the report variable from the two textboxes.

The source for the two textboxes would look something like this:

```
=Variables!TestVariable.Value
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255208(SQL.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255208%28SQL.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try the report variable. :-)

Comment: I was able to create the variable but could not figure out how populate the variable. I would like to populate it at the time the report has a value in TextBoxSubTotal. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried referencing the value in your textbox using `ReportItems!TextBoxSubTotal.Value`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried it but it states it's not in the same grouping scope. TextBoxSubTotal is in Tablix2. Is it possible to include Tablix2 as part of the ReportItems!TextBoxSubTotal.Value statement?

Comment: In Visual Studio go to Report/Report Properties. Then click Variables. Create a new variable, give it a name and in the Value field add your expression. `=Sum(Fields!LineTotal.Value), "DataSetOrGroupNameGoesHere")`

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution! :-) I had the take the ")" out from .Value since it was too many brakets and called the variable from the field using this expression: =variables!SubTotal.Value and the subtotal appeared.