# Class '<classname>' cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created a custom code block for the first time in a report.

When the report is previewed this error is displayed:

```
Class '<classname>' cannot be indexed because it has no default property
```

I am trying to populate a report field with a value. Here is the code in the custom block:

```
Sub PopulateSubTotal

    Fields!HeaderSubTotal.Value = Fields!TextboxSubTotal.Value
End Sub
```

Please tell me what I did wrong as this is my first attempt at using custom code blocks in a report.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error and the class name is `ReportExprHostImpl.CustomCodeProxy`, you may have written an expression with `Code!MyFunction(...)` instead of `Code.MyFunction(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution was found.

I found out this can't be done in a custom code block so I used a variable instead.

Please reference this posting for the answer:

[Displaying the value of a textbox in other parts of a report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063196/displaying-the-value-of-a-textbox-in-other-parts-of-a-report/10063368#comment12899732_10063368)